# Set element visibility by model value

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, visibility

I want to set the visibility of TextBox-elements based on their bindings.
Example:
TextBoxes with price values for two products

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding PriceProduct0, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding PriceProduct1, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

In my model, I query the necessary values from a WCF service and call NotifyPropertyChanged to update my view.
The problem: in some scenarios, there are no values for my properties. In that case I want to hide the UI element. Is there an easy way, maybe by raising an event?

Most of the properties are double or boolean, so I can't set them NULL.

**Solution:**
I found a solution, thanks to Ahmed and DHN!
Here all steps:

1. Change all non-nullable properties to nullables, e.g.
   `public double? PriceProduct0`
2. Add a reference to the following .dll, if you can't find the namespace
   `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.WPF.Converters`:
   `<VSHome>\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.dll`
3. Add `xmlns:myConverters="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.WPF.Converters;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls"` to the `<Page>` attribute
4. Add
   `<Page.Resources>

       <myConverters:NullToVisibleConverter x:Key="NullToVisibleConverter" />

   </Page.Resources>`
5. Add the following visibility parameter to the `<TextBox>` attribute:
   `Visibility="{Binding PriceProduct0, Converter={StaticResource NullToVisibleConverter}, ConverterParameter='invert' }"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use null to visibility converter. See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh725061.aspx)

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding PriceProduct0}" Visibility="{Binding PriceProduct0, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource NullToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Ahmed and DHN, but my properties are mostly double or boolean. Therefore I can't set them NULL or did I understand sth. wrong?

Comment: Found a solution by changing them to Nullable<T> properties (see my post)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing easier as this. Just a `NullToVisibleConverter` and bind it to the `Visibility` property of the UI element. E.g.

```
<Window>
    <Window.Resources>
        <NullToVisibleConverter x:Key="Null2VisConv"/>
    </Window.Resources>
<TextBox Visibility="{Binding PriceProduct0, Converter={StaticResource Null2VisConv}}" .../>
</Window>
```